# Update local file based on last-modified value of web version

Tags: apache, http, last-modified

I'm developing a NativeScript app in which I want to download a data file if a web version is newer.  I planned to use an http HEAD request and examine the Last-Modified value.  What I've discovered is that Last-Modified isn't always returned in the http response.  It is for .txt files, but not for .html or .db files.  This appears to be an apache config setting, but I can't find anything that controls that.

Any clues as to how to get Last-Modified returned in the http header for a .db file?

Answer (score 0):

After much searching and experimenting, this approach seems to work…

I created a new folder, /db/ and placed my sqlite database file in that folder.  I also added a .htaccess file with this line:

```
AddType application/x-sqlite3 .db
```

Now, when I issue an http HEAD request, the Last-Modified value is returned.  The .htaccess file applies to everything in the containing folder, which is why I created the new folder to avoid unwanted side effects.  Your mileage may vary, of course, as this depends on how the server is configured.